# Date validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

How can I validate date with javascript (onkeyup).My requirement is "Terminate date cannot be less than start date". Please give some links.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the date objects in your keyup event like this:

```
 if ( new Date(startDate.value) > new Date(terminateDate.value) ) {
     alert(true);
} else {
   alert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
var endDate = new Date($('#endDate').val());

if (startDate > endDate)
{
    // Your JS stuff.
}
```